# Se oculta una parte del contenido al realizar una función

Tags: javascript, php

tengo implementado un buscador con autocompletado para seleccionar un articulo, este tras mostrar los artículos en una lista y escoger el deseado con la función "seleccion" lo muestra en el cuadro de input y tras hacerlo oculta la lista con esto:

```
function seleccion(referencia){

document.getElementById("busqueda").value = referencia
// ocultar la lista tras obtener el articulo.
listado.style.display = "none"
}
```

Supuestamente funciona bien, pero si añado mas código en el archivo js para implementar otro evento oculta la parte inferior del contenido donde quiero que se vayan añadiendo articulos a una tabla. Seguro que es una tontería de novato pero estoy iniciandome en la programación y me encuentro con este error. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Archivo js inicial:

```
    document.getElementById("busqueda").addEventListener("keyup", buscarArticulos)

function buscarArticulos(){

var inputBuscar  = document.getElementById("busqueda").value
var listado = document.getElementById("listado")

// Validacion si input de busqueda tiene algo muestro elementos <li>.
if (inputBuscar.length > 0) {

    var url = "http://localhost/proyectoTest/buscador.php"
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("busqueda", inputBuscar)

    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    }).then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
    .then(datos => {
        listado.style.display = "block"
        listado.innerHTML = datos
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    } else { // si el input no tiene nada oculto <li>.
        listado.style.display = "none"
    }
}

function seleccion(referencia){

document.getElementById("busqueda").value = referencia
// ocultar la lista tras obtener el articulo.
listado.style.display = "none"
}
```

Capturas funcionamiento correcto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo js añadiendo mas código:

```
    document.getElementById("busqueda").addEventListener("keyup", buscarArticulos)

function buscarArticulos(){

var inputBuscar  = document.getElementById("busqueda").value
var listado = document.getElementById("listado")

// Validacion si input de busqueda tiene algo muestro elementos <li>.
if (inputBuscar.length > 0) {

    var url = "http://localhost/proyectoTest/buscador.php"
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("busqueda", inputBuscar)

    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    }).then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
    .then(datos => {
        listado.style.display = "block"
        listado.innerHTML = datos
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    } else { // si el input no tiene nada oculto <li>.
        listado.style.display = "none"
    }
}

function seleccion(referencia){

document.getElementById("busqueda").value = referencia
// ocultar la lista tras obtener el articulo.
listado.style.display = "none"
}

var btnAgregar = document.getElementById('anadir');
var btnGuardar = document.getElementById('Guardar');
var listado = document.getElementById('articulosCompra');
var articulos =[];
var cantidad=0;
btnAgregar.addEventListener("click", agregar)

function agregar() {
var referencia = document.getElementById('referencia').value;
var descripcion = document.getElementById('descrip').value;
var ctd  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ctd').value);
var precio  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('precio').value);
var coste = parseFloat(document.getElementById('coste').value);
var total = ctd*precio;
console.log(total);

}
```

Captura tras añadir codigo al archivo js
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entendí el problema

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema radica en que como ves en la ultima captura al hacer la funcion de click para seleccionar el articulo parte del contenido de la pagina desaparece y ademas la lista de articulos sigue presente y no paso de ahí. Lo que quiero conseguir es que una vez seleccionado el artículo me lo muestre en los input de debajo de la busqueda para modificar cantidad, precio, etc. y una vez hecho esto poder incluirlos en la tabla de mas abajo para realizar la compra de varios articulos a la vez. No se si me estoy complicando y quizas haya una forma mas facil de realizarlo.

Comment: Y en consola te aparece algún error?

Comment: Buenas , Prueba meter el listener de btn_agregar fuera de la función

Comment: En consola no hay ningun error Yussef, solo que la lista no se oculta tras hacer click

Comment: @rexxarcat No se a que te refieres  con sacar el listener btn_agregar, si te fijas en el codigo la funcion "seleccion" que es el que precede a la de agregar se cierra y seguidamente comienza esta ultima.

Comment: Verdad toda la razón no me habia dado cuenta